# Sending multiple patch and post methods to the same location

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a page `/users/:id` as the show page for the users. On the show page I am trying to update 2 tables in the database. Will be 4 tables at the end. I'm using these routes to do it.

```
devise_for :users
resources :users, only: [:show] 

patch '/users/:id' => 'companyinfos#update'
post '/users/:id' => 'companyinfos#update'
patch '/users/:id' => 'socials#update'
post '/users/:id' => 'socials#update'
```

I'm running into an error when doing this. If I try to update information for `socials#update` it's directing me to `companyinfos#update` method, but when I update companyinfos it works just fine. I'm assuming because I listed companyinfos route first. How do I properly route to the same location and update multiple methods.

Comment: Please add the update method from your socials controller.

Comment: You can't do that. Instead of trying do that, why not call social update in companyinfos#update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only update everything in 1 action by using [Active Record Nested Attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

```
## config/routes.rb
devise_for :users
resources :users, only: [:show, :create, :update] 


## models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :companyinfos, :socials
end

## controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  .........

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      .........
  end

  def update
    if @user.update(user_params)
      ......
  end

  private

  def user_params
    ## companyinfos_attributes and socials_attributes are generated by using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :abc, :xyz, companyinfos_attributes: [:id, :name, ...], socials_attributes: [:id, :name, ...])
  end
end


## users/_form.html.erb

<%= form_for user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input_field :name %>
  <%= f.input_field :abc %>
  <%= f.input_field :xyz %>
  ....

  <%= f.fields_for :companyinfos do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.input_field :name %> # This is companyinfos.name not user.name
  <% end %>


  <%= f.fields_for :socials do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.input_field :name %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

This is a good screencast. [[link]](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)